# Stuck with Jquery animate infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying create bubbles, after few repetitions my browser getting stuck. here is my code. someone please help.... How do I get it done with out making many requests .

It looks like my post is mostly code , but I added enough details for this Stackoverflow :)

Thanks!

**Jquery:**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

                           function bubbles()
                       {


                       var i = 0;


                      $(".circle").remove();



                       for(i = 0; i < 3; i ++ )

                       {

                             var CreateDiv =   document.createElement('div');

                      var AppendElem =  document.body.appendChild(CreateDiv);

                      AppendElem.setAttribute('class','circle');

                      CreateDiv.style.position = "absolute";

                      var randomPosTop = Math.floor((Math.random() * 800) + 1);

                      CreateDiv.style.top = randomPosTop +"px";

                       var randomPosLeft = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1200) + 1);

                       CreateDiv.style.left = randomPosLeft +"px";

                        }

                        $( ".circle" ).animate({ opacity :0.0,height:100, width:100 }, 5000,bubbles);


                       }

                       bubbles();


                       });
```

**CSS**

```
        .circle{ width: 20px;
                 height: 20px;
                 background-color: #000;
                 border-radius: 100px; position:absolute;}
```

**jsfiddle**

```
     https://jsfiddle.net/krishnakamal549/u4krxq8o/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the callback in the animation gets called for each element it finds.  So.. the first time it gets called 3 times, the second time 9, the third time 18, it gets tripled each time, eventually you're running hundreds of instances of "bubbles".

You want to use a promise to do the callback like so.

```
   $(".circle").animate({
     opacity: 0.0,
     height: 100,
     width: 100
   }, 5000).promise().done(bubbles);
```

This way, the callback only fires once for the entire animation, not per element.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/u4krxq8o/1/)

Comment: Thanks alot smeegs but in localhost it is not working. in console it is showing   $(...).animate(...).promise is not a function but working perfect in fiddle. why? Iam just started coding few months back, so please spare me if i sound stupid ... to trigger bubbles function onload all I added $(document).ready(function) {  //your code });

Comment: It could be the jquery version or the doctype of the html page.

Comment: I would also try to debug the error.  Remove the promise and see if you still get the error, then remove the animate and see if you get the error.  Try to narrow down the code to see which part is undefined.

Comment: According to the jquery documentation http://api.jquery.com/promise/ promise is supported in jquery 1.6 and above.

Comment: oh yes I was using 1.4 . thats why it was not working.. now I updated with latest version and it is working. :)  I am really thankful for you help .

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".circle").animate({
   opacity: 0.0,
   height: 100,
   width: 100
}, 5000);

$("body").animate({ opacity: 1 }, 5000, bubbles);
```

Try this, this also works. **But i suggest to use [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35532065/3474961) specified by Smeegs.**

This method adds an extra process to the `body` for an animation while approach by Smeegs directly deals where the animation is applied and no need for an extra animation process on `body`